# Closing/launching an application when Windows 7 sleeps/wakes up

Tags: windows-7

I'm trying to get a legacy VB6/C++ application to work on Windows 7. The application can't handle "Windows 7 Sleep"; if Windows 7 is put to sleep and is woken up again then the application stops working.

I would be home free if I could close the application when Windows 7 goes to sleep and re-launch the application when Windows 7 is woken up again. (I don't need to store any state between application runs). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "stops working", does it crash? Can you include the crash dump in that case and show us the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to [process OS events](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20120718133254/http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30089/Handling-OS-Events-in-Windows-XP-and-Vista) and the .NET equivalent is [a PowerModeChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.powermodechanged.aspx).

Another option is to schedule tasks with the Task Manager to trigger on the sleep and resume events...